# Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Tags: python, pandas, row, indexer, pandas-loc

Using python, there are something wrong.

```
 resource1   #"dataframe"
```

and,

```
resource1.loc[(resource1["code"] == ""), "code"] = "nocode"
```

then, error message is here.

> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:537:
>   SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
>   slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] =
>   value instead See the caveats in the documentation:
>   http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
>   self.obj[item] = s

What's wrong with the code?

Comment: You need to post your data, code to reproduce your df, and code that reproduces your error, looking at your scant code, why do you need `()` around the boolean mask? does this work: `resource1.loc[resource1["code"] == "", "code"] = "nocode"`

Comment: As @EdChum wrote you need to show how you generated your data. Looking at your error messages suggests that you probably created resource1 using a slice, e.g:

    `resource1 = resource1.loc[resource1["Code"] == "special_code"]`

Answer (score 3):

If you created resource1 from another source i.e. like this:

```
# original DattaFrame
resource = pd.DataFrame({'code':['aaa', "", 'bb', 'nbn']})
# new DataFrame 
resource1 = resource[resource['code'].str.len()<3]
```

You get the warning message (but *resource1* has been modified). The reason probably is that *resource1* is created as a filter from *resource* and it's not clear if it returns copy or view - a refference to *resources* instead of new variable (see this [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) for more details). To avoid this you may use deepcopy function

```
import copy
resource1 = copy.deepcopy(resource[resource['code'].str.len()<3])
```

This securely creates brand new DataFrame with filtered data and your code

```
resource1.loc[(resource1["code"] == ""), "code"] = "nocode"
```

will work without warning.

Or you may disable chained assignment to reach the same (but warnings are not just anoying, so consider the option carefuly...)

```
pandas.options.mode.chained_assignment = None
```